# Resteasy Atom Links with Jackson instead of Jettison

Tags: json, jackson, resteasy, hateoas, jettison

Due to other requirements we need to use Jackson for JSON serialization. Unfortunately Jackson does not support Atom Links with RESTServiceDiscovery as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/LinkHeader.html). Has anyone already build a workaround for this? Or any idea why it is not working with Jackson and how to fix it?

Our current approach is to use XML as output and then use a javascript library to transform XML to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the same problem using JBossAS7.
We ended switching from Jackson to Jettison by disabling Jackson in jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need Jackson since Jettison does not support JSONP.

Comment: @Leonard Brünings - You could always switch to Jettison and then handle wrapping/unwrapping your JSONP messages in a servlet filter.